# Any possible way to directly write on Bluetooth Device (from C++/Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I've read some parts of the Qt 5.10 Bluetooth documentation and follow the [Scan tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-lowenergyscanner-example.html) to discover the services, characteristics and descriptors of my device.

It works nice but I need to wait few seconds between each interaction (like, move into a service to list every characteristics).

My question is, can I directly access to a descriptor or a characteristic to write/read directly the data ? And how ?

I have static addresses and I will always use them on every bluetooth devices. I need to write just with the Service/Characteristic/Descriptor combination.
On Ionic, I'm doing it with the [Cordova BluetoothLE Plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) and it works fine.

Can anyone help me ? Thank you very much !